# Impossible to run .sh Script with crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

i am trying to schedule my script.sh script to run every day from monday to friday at 9:35 am. When I run my script with ./ directly in the terminal everything works fine. But when I tried to run in the crontab -e nothing worked.
Here is the list of what I tried:

```
- * * * * * root /bin/script.sh
- * * * * * root sh /bin/script.sh
- * * * * * root bash /bin/script.sh
- * * * * * root / bin / sh /bin/script.sh
- * * * * * /bin/script.sh
- * * * * * sh /bin/script.sh
- * * * * * bash /bin/script.sh
- * * * * * / bin / sh /bin/script.sh
```

I put an execution every minute just for the test.
Otherwise the final command will be something like this:

```
- 35 9 * * 1-5 /bin/script.sh
```

I must have forgotten an important step or something.
Of course I restartcron with each modification with:

```
- service cron restart
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /bin/script.sh
```

You can also add a shebang in the beginning of your script

```
#!/bin/bash

... your script here ...
```

This will let you execute the script directly by calling it with /bin/script.sh
The system will know that he need to start bash to execute it
You will need to get execution access right

```
chmod +x /bin/script.sh
```

This will give execution rights to anyone, check chmod man if you want to give execution access to only owner

The cron will be just like that

```
* * * * * /bin/script.sh
```

Keep in mind you will not get any output with a cron, you can still redirect stdout to a log file

```
* * * * * /bin/script.sh >> /var/log/myscript.log
```

If you use crontab -e as root, you don't need to use sudo or anything like that

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I have already done that too :)

Comment: @LyesBenchoubane You done that ? And it still not working ? Or it was successful ?

Comment: I try add log file. I tell you soon ! Thanks

Comment: So I try to add * * * * * /bin/script.sh >> /var/log/myscript.log, restart wait 3 minutes. But no output. I need to create myscript.log ? (I don't think)

Comment: No, it should create itself. Check if there's any error in /var/log/syslog
You can do grep CRON /var/log/syslog to get all cron related errors

Comment: I have 
- INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
- CMD (/bin/sh /bin/script.sh)
- INFO (skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
- INFO (no MTA installed, discarding outpout)

Comment: Doesn't looks like an error to me.
MTA is used to send mail alert, so you don't have any configured, it's normal.
Maybe you don't have right to write on your /var/log directory
Can you try to change the output to >> ~/myscript.log ?
This should create the log under your home folder

Comment: By the way, are you using cron with root or other user ?
Is this a Ubuntu based distri ?